# Stored procedure is returning false value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure for getting the count from a column but when I execute the procedure its returning a date value. While separate query execution returns the required result set.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_ViewAdminDashBoard](@LoginUser varchar(75)) 
AS 
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @LastLoginDate  as DateTime 

    Select  @LastLoginDate = dbo.UDF_GetLastLoginByUser(@LoginUser);

    Select  'Last Login Date', @LastLoginDate 
    Union
    Select  'No. Active Business Associates' as Title, COUNT(isActive) Total 
    from    (select 1)d(isActive)
    where   isActive = 1 
  Union Select 'New Registration Today' as Title, COUNT(1) Total from dbo.TBL_iREGFORM     where isActive = 1 And GETDATE()>= RegDate
 Union Select 'Registration Pending for Verification' as Title, COUNT(1) Total from dbo.TBL_iREGFORM where isActive = 1 and isVerified = 1
END
```

Comment: Can you provide your actual query?

Comment: There isn't much anyone will be able to tell you without being able to see the query.

Comment: Sorry For Formatting ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are UNION-ing a datetime `@LastLoginDate` with an integer,  `COUNT(isActive)`.

This is causing the implicit conversion you are experiencing. To return these values in the same query you will need to convert them into a common datatype, likely varchar. Or, you can use two distinct queries.

If you do choose to continue with the union, be sure to use UNION ALL instead.  Read more [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/).

Comment: thanks for help pal.i need to type cast every single select query.or go with two different select..

Comment: yep, the date value you are seeing is your integer from the count cast as a date.  (int)0 = (datetime)1900-01-00